# Changing the class of the html document using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to jQuery. I need to add a class called "success" to every paragraph in divClass when button btnClassPSuccess is clicked. 
My HTML code is :-

```
<div id="divClass">
  <p>A</p>
  <p>B</p>
  <p>C</p>
  <p>D</p>
  <p>E</p>
  <p>F</p>
  <p>G</p>
</div>
<button id="btnClassPSuccess">Change Paragraphs to Success</button>
```

My jQuery code is :-

```
$("#btnClassPSuccess").click(function () {
  $('#divClass').addClass("sucess");
});
```

Can you please correct me how to do this.

Comment: Try this to add class on all paragraph inside a div $("#divClass p").addClass("succcess")

Comment: If divClass is a class name then use dot instead of #

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$("#btnClassPSuccess").click(function () {
  $('#divClass p').addClass("success");
});
```

```css
.success{
 background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divClass">
 <p>A</p>
 <p>B</p>
 <p>C</p>
 <p>D</p>
 <p>E</p>
 <p>F</p>
 <p>G</p>
</div>
<button id="btnClassPSuccess">Change Paragraphs to Success</button>
```

I see your edit now:

```
$("#btnClassPSuccess").click(function () {
  $('#divClass p').addClass("success");
});
```

try it

Answer (score 2):

You'd do it like:

```
$("#btnClassPSuccess").click(function () {
    $('#divClass p').addClass("success");
});
```

Example:

```js
$("#btnClassPSuccess").click(function() {
  $('#divClass').addClass("success");
});
```

```css
.success {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divClass">
  <p>A</p>
  <p>B</p>
  <p>C</p>
  <p>D</p>
  <p>E</p>
  <p>F</p>
  <p>G</p>
</div>
<button id="btnClassPSuccess">Change Paragraphs to Success</button>
```